# C# Autoinstall required .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-4.5.2

I am sure i've seen something like that but my googleskills really dont provide me with a solution!

I have build a mail programm that actually requires `.net 4.5.2`

It should be and stay in this .net because I have a special usage for my tool. So some clients (windows-user) using win 7 and they dont have basicly installed the required version.

If I want to start my application, it throws an exaptation that the target framework isnt installed. Now I want to offer the chance to say **Download .net 4.5.2** but my app is and c# app and actaully requires .net in anyway, otherwise it wont start at all.

So my question (to keep it short) is:

Can I Prompt a required .net Framework-Download ?

Or is it possible to say windows to update the .net?

Comment: Take a look at ClickOnce deployment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x.aspx

Comment: You need to make an installer package for your program. The installer package can prompt users to install the required .net version.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen i guess this one should not be made by my self in c#? more like inno-setup or as Dai announced in ClickOnce ???

Comment: @Dai this msdn link obviously saved my day :D